# proximity symbol in Circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

A proximity symbol would be nice to have in Circuitikz. Here are examples: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-electrical/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-Electrical/files/GUID-1B18023D-241C-4E50-822A-94F873FC258B-htm.html

I improvise  using \ctikzsubcircuitdef, but an embed symbol would be great.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx,american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}  

\begin{document}

\ctikzsubcircuitdef{proximeter}{in, out, center}{% reference anchor is -center
coordinate(#1-center)
(#1-center) +(-0.5,0)coordinate (#1-in)  +(0.5,0)coordinate (#1-out) 
(#1-in) to[ecsource] (#1-out)  
(#1-center)++(-0.35,0.15) to ++(0.7,0)
(#1-center)++(-0.35,-0.15) to ++(0.7,0)
% leave the position of the path at the center
(#1-center) 
}

\ctikzsubcircuitactivate{proximeter}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[rotate=0] (2,0) \proximeter{PS}{};

  \draw[rotate=90] (0,0) \proximeter{PS}{};
  \draw (PS-in) --++(0,-1) coordinate(PS1) 
        (PS-out) --++(0,1) coordinate(PS2); 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is? Thanks.

Comment: Symbol/Component requests are better made at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues --- I will try to generate a kind of issue for them, but notice that developers (i.e., my ;-)) time is quite limited. But a nicely done request can have somebody pick it up... Anyway, very "niche" component are better implemented by subcircuit.

Comment: Anyway, please try to post complete, compilable snippets --- that would maximize the probability of an answer by minimizing the answerer time needed... ;-)

Comment: Some of the linked symbols can be implement by sticking those fancy diamonds next to normal switches.

Comment: I edited a MWE that compiles! I tried posting an issue in the GitHub-circuitikz, but I could not get it through (:-/. Above all, I'm a fan of CircuiTikz  and I deeply appreciate all the great work that has been made with Circuitikz.

Comment: The code you posted works quite well... ;-). Why did you not manage to open an issue on GitHub? That's strange... (I will try to add a generic symbol for this --- when I find a spot; could be something like the symbols that are provided for hysteresis for example)

Comment: @Rmano,  I tried before to post an issue in github but it didn't work. I've just tried again and it got through. Thanks for your kind and swift attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version [will be added to `v1.5.2`](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/632):

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\makeatletter
% proximeter shape, for usage with switches
\ctikzset{proximeter/width/.initial=0.3}
\ctikzset{proximeter/hlines thickness/.initial=0.5}
\ctikzset{proximeter/hlines position/.initial=0.3}
\pgfdeclareshape{proximeter}
{
    \savedmacro{\ctikzclass}{\edef\ctikzclass{switches}}
    \saveddimen{\scaledRlen}{\pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}\pgf@circ@Rlen}}
    \savedmacro{\hlinepos}{\edef\hlinepos{\ctikzvalof{proximeter/hlines position}}}
    \savedanchor\northeast{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@y}{\ctikzvalof{proximeter/width}*\ctikzvalof{\ctikzclass/scale}*\pgf@circ@Rlen}
        \pgf@x=\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{center}{\pgfpointorigin}
    % geo anchors based on north-east
    \pgfcirc@northeast@symmetric@geoanchors
    \anchor{text}{%
        \northeast
        \pgf@x=\dimexpr -.5\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox\relax
        \advance\pgf@y by .6\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox\relax
    }
    \anchor{hlines ne}{%
        \northeast
        \pgf@y=\hlinepos\pgf@y
        \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{hlines nw}{%
        \northeast
        \pgf@y=\hlinepos\pgf@y
        \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@y\pgf@x=-\pgf@x
    }
    \anchor{hlines se}{%
        \northeast
        \pgf@y=\hlinepos\pgf@y
        \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@y
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchor{hlines sw}{%
        \northeast
        \pgf@y=\hlinepos\pgf@y
        \advance\pgf@x by -\pgf@y\pgf@x=-\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
    }
    \anchorborder{
        % \typeout{IN\space X:\the\pgf@x\space Y:\the\pgf@y}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\@@switchx}{ifthenelse(\pgf@x>0,1,-1)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\@@switchy}{ifthenelse(\pgf@y>0,1,-1)}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{abs(\pgf@x)}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@ya}{abs(\pgf@y)}
        \pgfextracty{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\northeast}
        % \typeout{MID\space X:\the\pgf@xa\space Y:\the\pgf@ya\space L:\the\pgf@circ@res@up}
        % \typeout{MID\space SX:\@@switchx\space SY:\@@switchy}
        \pgfpointintersectionoflines
            {\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
            {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@circ@res@up}{0pt}}
        % \typeout{CROSS \space X:\the\pgf@x\space Y:\the\pgf@y}
        \pgf@x=\@@switchx\pgf@x
        \pgf@y=\@@switchy\pgf@y
    }
    \pgf@circ@draw@component{
        \northeast\pgf@circ@res@temp=\pgf@y
        \pgf@circ@setcolor
        \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{tripoles}{\pgflinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@temp}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\pgf@circ@res@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@temp}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-\pgf@circ@res@temp}}
        \pgfpathclose
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\ctikzvalof{proximeter/hlines thickness}*\pgflinewidth}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@res@up}{\hlinepos*\pgf@circ@res@temp}
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@temp-\pgf@circ@res@up}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-\pgf@circ@res@right}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{-\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}
    }

}
\pgfcirc@node@to@path{proximeter}{inline proximeter}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{small up proxi/.style={proximeter, solid,
            circuitikz/switches/scale=0.707,
            circuitikz/proximeter/hlines thickness=1,
            circuitikz/proximeter/hlines position=0.1}}
    \draw (0,0) to[inline proximeter, l=P1] ++(2,0)
        to[ccgsw, name=P2] ++(2,0);
    \draw[dashed] (P2.mid) -- ++(0,0.5)
        node[small up proxi, above](P2p){Fe}
        (P2p.north) ++ (0,0.5); % extend bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```